# How to get content that isn't loaded yet?

Tags: php, curl, get

I need to get content from ANOTHER SERVER web page, but when I use `file_get_content($url)`, URL won't show up for certain page probably because it isn't loaded yet.

Is there any option to get content if page loads dynamically for couple of seconds?

---

For example, I need to load `oddsportal.com/matches` with all matches and odds, but when U use `file_get_content('oddsportal.com/matches')` in my PHP code, these things won't show up. Why? Probably cause of dynamic content loading.

Maybe I can load content into an iframe and then wait for completely load and on someway get content from iframe?

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your reply. For example, i need to load http://www.oddsportal.com/matches all matches and odds, but when i use file_get_content('http://www.oddsportal.com/matches') in my php code, these things won't show up. why? Probably cause of dinamyc content loading. I hope you'll understand now

Answer (score 0):

Use JQuery for this.

```
<div id="url-contents"></div>

<script>
$( "#url-contents" ).load( "your/url.html" );
</script>
```

Comment: yes, but I need a content from another serve. I'm afraid that it will not work

Comment: Please do not answer overly broad questions because, as the comment suggests, you may not have all of the information you need to provide a good answer.